# ol-ext Control Bar and function in the Controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, openlayers

I have an extjs app in which I am using an ol-ext control bar. The control bar is in the file *MyApp.js* and the function that I want to call clicking on the button belonging the control bar is in the relative controller *MyAppController*. 
In MyApp.js:

```js
var testFuction = function(){
   return this.getController().updateImages;
};

var mainbar = new ol.control.Bar();
var first = new ol.control.Button (
 {
       html: '1',
       //handler: 'updateImages',
       //reference: 'locationShowImageButton',
        handleClick: testFuction,
 });
       
//Standard Controls
mainbar.addControl (first);
mainbar.setPosition('bottom-right');
this.map.addControl(mainbar);
```

In MyAppController:

```js
updateImages: function (obj) {
            var self = this;
            this.getView().cleanImageLayers();
            var selectedFloors = ; //it should be the value of the  ol.control.Button, so 1
            if (this.lookupReference('locationShowImageButton').pressed) {
               .....
```

Comment: Can you attach an exception/error which occurs? Is the function `updateImages` called?

Comment: Yes I have an error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.getController is not a function`

Comment: It's like a can not communicate with the function of the controller and make the function of the controller know that I pressed the button of the control bar.

Comment: `MyAppController` it's a ViewController? Maybe you should use `handleClick:'updateImages'` instead of `handleClick:testFuction` in `first button`.

Comment: Yes. I tried and it give me the error  `options.handleClick.call is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if `this.getController()` in `MyApp.js` refer to `MyAppController`.

> You can't use `ol.control.Button` like sencha component.

You should use `this` in your `MyApp.js` scope.

```
var mainbar = new ol.control.Bar();
var me = this;
var first = new ol.control.Button (
 {
        html: '1',
        handleClick: function () {
            me.getController().updateImages();
        }
 });

//Standard Controls
mainbar.addControl (first);
mainbar.setPosition('bottom-right');
this.map.addControl(mainbar);
```